# Highlighting Bold Text In PDF using Java

Tags: java, pdf, highlight

I'm trying to create a Java Program where it reads a pdf and highlights the words that are bolded. So far, PDFClown seems promising but none of the readers seem to support identifying bolded text. Does anyone have a recommendation on how I could accomplish this?

Comment: first get the font of the text using `getFont()` then compare it to the style enum

Comment: @Rathnayake why is itextsharp,  a *.Net library,* the best api "to create a Java Program..."? And even if you mean itext, the pendant for java,  you should show in which way it is better suited than pdfclown.

Comment: Be aware that many PDF creation tools don't use bold fonts to render text that has been styled to look bold. They simply overlay the same normal text 2 or three times with a slight offset so that it *looks* bold on the page but isn't actually the bold version of the font.